# Oracle APEX application security while IMPORT/EXPORT application to new environment

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I have oracle APEX database application which i built. While creating application i included Access control page so that i can manage user security for the application. When i created that in DEV i got added as administrator for that application. I also added few more users in access control as Reader and Contributors.

Now when i tried to import that application to new environment the users are not been moved with the application. So i am not able to login to the application in the new environment(i found a work around to add users but). How to copy all the access control users and their rights while importing the application so that i don't have to do work around and add them again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you have a very different set of users in a dev environment than in a production environment. Moreover, users are not part of your application, they're part of the environment your application is running in.
As per the docs, users are not exported (https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMDB/how-access-control-works.htm#GUID-BF6E5094-3B75-4BCD-8D05-DE6ACE6E974D).

If you do want to move your users from one environment to another then you have to do that yourself. You can brew your own scripts on the apex ACL views or check this [blog](https://seanstuber.com/2019/06/06/extracting-apex-access-control-users/)

Comment: Thank you. This definitely help using script and assigning user control